# Twig not detecting the custom function

Tags: php, symfony, twig, twig-extension, twig-filter

I have written a Twig custom function (in a Twig custom extension). I notice the template does not read the function and keeps throwing me the "Method Exists" error.
Was wondering if you have faced this before. Any ideas ?

The custom extension file; `$post` and `$list` are both objects:

```
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class ShowContentExtension extends AbstractExtension
{

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('ShowList', [$this, 'ShowList']),
            new TwigFunction('ShowPost', [$this, 'ShowPost'])
        ];
    }

    public function ShowList($list) {
        foreach ($list->post as $post) {
            $this->ShowPost($post);
        }
    }

    public function ShowPost($post) {
        return !((count(array_keys($post->documents))) < 2 && array_key_exists('header', $post->documents));
    }

}
```

and this is where they are being called:

```
{% if ShowList(list) %}
    <h2 >{{ title }}</h2>
    <div>
        <div>
            {% for post in list %}
                {% if post|length > 0 %}
                    {% include ./_links.html.twig' with  { 'list': list} %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
```

and :

```
{% if ShowPost(post) %}
<div>
    <div>
        <a href="{{ post.link }}">
            <span>{{ post.title }}</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

and this is the screenshot of the error :

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6N9g.png)

Comment: You can use `php bin/console debug:twig` to verify your extension is properly registered but I think `foreach ($list->post as $post)` and `{% for post in list %}` are the real culprits.  If you have a collection of posts then why not call it posts?

Comment: `{% ./_links.html.twig' with  { 'list': list} %}` is clearly a syntax error, that should be `{% include './_links.html.twig' with  { 'list': list} %}`. Please fix this first and let us know if this helped anything. Second, your function `ShowPost` does not return any value, thus nothing will be shown. You would need to adjust the function to `if ($this->ShowPost($post))) return true;`

Comment: yes, it was something that got missed out when I was typing up the question. The `include` is in the code.
`showPost` does return the value of `!((count(array_keys($post->documents))) < 2 && array_key_exists('header', $post->documents));` which is `true` or `false` .

Comment: No, it doesn't. Look at your function `showList`, you just loop all the posts, check the function `showPost` but never do anything with it.